# Sublime Text Plugin using applescript can not open FirefoxDeveloperEdition

Tags: applescript, sublime-text-plugin

I am having an issue getting applescript in a sublime text plugin to open Firefox Developer Edition.

```
cmd = """tell application "FirefoxDeveloperEdition"

activate

end tell"""

call(['osascript', '-e', cmd])
```

This works in the applescript editor activates FirefoxDeveloperEdition but doesn't work in the sublime text plugin.

I can swap out Firefox, Google Chrome and even Minecraft and they all work from with in the sublime text plugin. But it won't activate FirefoxDeveloperEdition.

Comment: I have it working. You have to use tell application "Firefox Developer Edition" (with spaces for it to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application name should have spaces.

```
tell application "Firefox Developer Edition"
```

Comment: Also it appears you can not have firefox open at the same time as firefox developer edition or it will open regular firefox instead. So it isn't working as precisely as I would expect.